# Xcode: Why does the Project structure not follow the Finder structure?

Tags: xcode, directory

It's an unusual design decision to make the project structure separate from the actual folder structure you see in Finder.

All the good projects I've followed (Stripe, React, Dropbox etc.) all seem to mirror their structures. It seems like a waste of time to ensure that the structures match.

Why did Apple make this decision?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is manytimes required, not to follow the same folder structure in your finder and code structure.

This gives you a lot of flexibility.

We can, however, keep the same structur using "Create folder references", while adding file/folder/resources.
[Refer this screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/79649352/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-24%20at%202.57.46%20pm.png).